# What is the relation between dimension of vector space and number of pairs of orthogonal vectors in that space

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, linear-algebra

In quantum mechanics when we say state of all states for a simple spin system is 2 dimensional.

Q1. Does it mean that there are only two independent states (states which can be unambiguously measureable) and rest of all states are just linear combinations of them?

Q2. Is it fair to say that independent states means orthogonal states?

Q3. In the same system, there are three pairs which are orthogonal to each other. Is there any relationship between dimensionality of the vector space and number of orthogonal pairs you can find?

Comment: This question uses a lot of non-standard phrases and makes several implicit assumptions that are not true. For example: *"In the same system, there are three pairs which are orthogonal to each other."* It's not clear what that means.

Comment: I am beginner in Quantum Mechanics and trying to make some sense of it. Could pls kindly point out the problems so that it helps me.

Comment: Three pairs as I am reading them seem to be Up and down, Left and right and In and out.

Answer (score 0):

This is really a maths question.

Given some vector space, you can consider sets of vectors $\{\vec{e}_i\}$ such that, for any vector $\vec{v}$, $\vec{v} = \sum_i v_i \vec{e}_i$, where the $\{v_i\}$ belong to the field the vector space is defined over, which for physics is usually the real or complex numbers.

Such a set $\{\vec{e}_i\}$ is called a *basis* for the space.

Now we can try to make that basis as small as possible by removing all elements $\vec{e}_i$ such that $\vec{e}_i = \sum_{j\ne i} e_j\vec{e}_j$: by removing all basis vectors which can be constructed from other basis vectors in other words.

This pruned basis set is called a *linearly-independent basis*: it's obvious that it's still a basis for the whole space (because if we 'need' one of the pruned vectors we can always make it from the remaining ones).

It is a theorem that all linearly-independent bases for a space are the same size: this number is the dimension of the space.

Now, consider a vector space equipped with an inner product, which I'll write as $\langle \vec{v},\vec{u}\rangle$, with the normal properties of an inner product.

Given an LI basis $\{\vec{e}_i\}$ it's possible to construct another basis $\left\{\vec{e'}_i\right\}$ where the $\vec{e'}_i$s are linear combinations of the $\vec{e}_i$s, and such that $\left\langle\vec{e'}_i,\vec{e'}_j\right\rangle = \delta_{ij}$.  I'm not going to show how to do this.

This basis (a) is LI, and (b) is orthonormal: the vectors in it are orthogonal to each other and any basis vector has unit length.  Because it is an LI basis then it has a number of vectors in it equal (by definition) to the dimension, and they are all orthogonal to each other.  So this is how many orthogonal vectors there are.

If you want to understand this in more detail (for instance to see proofs of the various things I've asserted, along with a lot less sloppiness), you should look at a book on linear algebra: people doing maths degrees would typically do this in their first year I think, so there are a huge range of texts.